# What does '&.' in '&.sub-title' indicates in scss?

Tags: css, sass

I am a newbie to CSS and SCSS.

In the following code,

```
.title {
    width: 718px;
    &.sub-title {
      width: 938px;
   }
}
```

What does **&.** means? Is it same as nesting class?

Answer (score 141, accepted):

The `&` concatenates the parent class, resulting in `.title.sub-title` (rather than `.title .sub-title` if the `&` is omitted).

The result is that with the `&` it matches an element with both `title` and `sub-title` classes:

```
<div class='title sub-title'></div> <!-- << match -->
```

whilst without the `&` it would match a descendent with class `sub-title` of an element with class `title`:

```
<div class='title'>
  ...
    <div class='sub-title'></div> <!-- << match -->
  ...
</div>
```

Comment: To make it a bit more clear .title.sub-title means elements that have both classes. .title .sub-title means that .subtitle is the descendant of .title