# What does the & mean in an scss selector?

Tags: css, sass, syntax, selector

What does `&` refer to in an scss selector?

```
    //Case 1

    .parent {
      & > ul {
        color: red
      }
    }

    //Case 2

    .parent {
      & > ul {
        & > li {
          color: blue;
        }
      } 
    }

    //Case 3

    .parent {
      & > ul {
        & > li {
          color: blue;
          &:hover {
            color: pink
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: This is in the docs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does '&.' in '&.sub-title' indicates in scss?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9988558/what-does-in-sub-title-indicates-in-scss)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The **&** is a placeholder for the parent selector:

```
.parent {
  & > ul {
    color: red
  }
}
```

Is the same like

```
.parent > ul {
  color: red
}
```

A common use case are pseudo classes, e.g.:

```
.link {
  &:hover {
    color: red
  }
}
```

A nice explanation with examples can be found on [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/the-sass-ampersand).

Comment: what about `&-` like `.class-name { &-foo` is it just including the hyphen?

Comment: @FlavorScape  you could. `But don’t.

You’ll never be able to search the project for ‘.class-name-foo’ for one example.` https://medium.com/@MentallyFriendly/scss-and-the-sassy-ampersand-411cc3b0927f