# Can you help me Interpreting `&` in Sass code?

Tags: javascript, css, dom, sass

This is DOM applying Sass.

```
<i className={`contract-icon ic-${this.props.value}`} />
```

This is Sass file.

```
.contract-icon {
    &.ic-rise_fall {
        &:before {
            content: url('../images/trading_app/contracts/rise_fall.svg');
        }
        &--invert:before { # What's this?
            content: url('../images/trading_app/contracts/invert/rise_fall.svg');
        }
    }
    .other-class {
        padding-right: 8px;
    }
    ...
```

Based on my research,

- `&` is combine/ join with this selector if the current element has the accompanying class applied.

  - (My Guess) So I thought we can build DOMs like this way: `<div class="contract-icon> <div class="ic-rise_fall">` -> But this is not right. Why is it wrong? How does it make a difference from `.contract-icon` class?
- (Bonus Question) What is `--invert:before`?

Comment: & means both classes are being applied on the same div(element)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does '&.' in '&.sub-title' indicates in scss?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9988558/what-does-in-sub-title-indicates-in-scss)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this line, you are actually applying two classes to the `i`, which are `contract-icon` and `ic-{something}` (In the example it is `ic-rise_fall`).

As you said `&` is used to combine the class names. Means:-

```
&.ic-rise_fall {
    &--invert:before { # What's this?
        content: url('../images/trading_app/contracts/invert/rise_fall.svg');
    }
}
```

This will be converted into

```
&.ic-rise_fall--invert:before {
    content: url('../images/trading_app/contracts/invert/rise_fall.svg');
}
```

in css.

So basically, the code

```
.contract-icon {
    &.ic-rise_fall {
        &:before {
            content: url('../images/trading_app/contracts/rise_fall.svg');
        }
        &--invert:before { # What's this?
            content: url('../images/trading_app/contracts/invert/rise_fall.svg');
        }
    }
    .other-class {
        padding-right: 8px;
    }
}
```

will be converted into

```
.contract-icon.ic-rise_fall:before {
    content: url('../images/trading_app/contracts/rise_fall.svg');
}
.contract-icon.ic-rise_fall--invert:before {
    content: url('../images/trading_app/contracts/invert/rise_fall.svg');
}
.contract-icon .other-class {
    padding-right: 8px;
}
```

Like this.

This `ic-{something}` is being passed as `props` from the parent, so, it can be either `ic-rise_fall` or `ic-rise_fall--invert`. So we are just handling the possibilities of using SASS here.

```
<span class='contract-icon ic-rise_fall'>
   <i class='other-class'></i>
</span>
```

Consider this as the case where you applied the `other-class` and `ic-rise_fall`

Comment: could you please answer my bonus question too

Comment: What about the `.contract-icon`?

Comment: no. I just changed `.contract-icon` child to `.other-class`

Comment: Just edited my answer too. Find your answer and feel free to clear your doubts.

Comment: So why is it putting `&` before `ic-rise-_fall`? It works same as `other-class though`.

Comment: I am sorry, I missed a space between `.contract-icon .other-class` before. Check again

Answer (score 3):

[& is to reference the parent selector](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#parent-selector).

It's really easy to understand what it does. You can say it's like to **append** the parent selector. Or, think of it this way.

So let's say you want to apply multiple styles to `.container`, which its standard css is:

1. `.container.success`,
2. `.container.success.but-stupid`,
3. `.container.successful`,
4. `.container > div.error`,
5. `.container ~ div.stupid`,
6. `.container-----_happy-sass`

And in SASS, you can do it like,

```
.container { /* this is 1 */
    &.success { 
        &.but-stupid { /* this is 2 */ }
        &ful { /* this is 3 */  }
    }

    & > div.error { /* this is 4 */ }

    & ~ div.stupid { /* this is 5 */ }

    &-----_happy-sass { /* this is 6 */ }
}
```

Or, in your case above,

```
.contract-icon {
    &.ic-rise_fall {  /* EQUALS TO .contract-icon.ic-rise_fall */
        &:before { /* EQUALS TO .contract-icon.ic-rise_fall:before; */
            /*declarations*/
        }
        &--invert:before { /* EQUALS TO .contract-icon.ic-rise_fall--invert */
            /*declarations*/
        }
    }

    .other-class { /* EQUALS TO .contract-icon .other-class */
        /*declarations*/
    }
}
```

Comment: What about `.other-class` in `contact-icon`?

Comment: @JohnBaek It equals to `.contract-icon.other-class`. Please check the updated answer.

Comment: Nop, it is equal to `.contract-icon .other-class`

Comment: Thanks for your contribution @choz. I'm very sorry that I can choose only one answer. Your explanation is clear and I'm sure it will be helpful for Stackoverflow community. I voted up your answer.

Comment: @JohnBaek Sure, I just hope this helps.

Comment: It helped! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can say the "**&**" is the upper parent. for example,

This is the SASS with **&**.

```
.contract-icon {
    &.ic-rise_fall {
        &:before {
            content: url('../images/trading_app/contracts/rise_fall.svg');
        }
        &--invert:before { # What's this?
            content: ''
    }
  }
}
```

this is the compiled CSS of **&**. It will select the selector which are same level

```
.contract-icon.ic-rise_fall:before {
  content: url("../images/trading_app/contracts/rise_fall.svg");
}
.contract-icon.ic-rise_fall--invert:before {
  content: "";
}
```

This is the SASS without **&**.

```
   .contract-icon {
      .ic-rise_fall {
            &:before {
                content: url('../images/trading_app/contracts/rise_fall.svg');
            }
      }
    }
```

The compiled CSS without **&**. It will select child element

```
 .contract-icon .ic-rise_fall:before {
  content: url("../images/trading_app/contracts/rise_fall.svg");
}
```

It helps to directly attach the parent selector