# What does &- mean in &-link in the below code?

Tags: sass

I am new to scss. What does &- mean in the below code ?

```css
        .btn{
          border: 0;
          font-size: 14px;
          font-weight: bold;  
          &-link {
              background-color: $white;
              color: $orange;
          }
        }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does '&.' in '&.sub-title' indicates in scss?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9988558/what-does-in-sub-title-indicates-in-scss)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```css
.btn{
   &-link {
      background-color: $white;
      color: $orange;
   }
}
```

Will be compiled into:

```css
.btn-link {
   background-color: $white;
   color: $orange;
}
```

Reference: https://css-tricks.com/the-sass-ampersand/#modifying-the-ampersand